# Scraping elements from table using API method

Tags: pandas, api, web-scraping, python-requests

Please help me with my code. I want the names of the ingredients to be printed separated by comma. I want all the first elements only. I've also uploaded a sample image for better understanding, the red circles are all I need. The result should be comma separated like (Aqua,Butylene Glycol,Cyclopentasiloxane,Triethylhexanoin) [image: Sample Image of ingredients list]

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
Id=[]
for page_num in tqdm(range(1,19)):
    json_page = requests.get('https://mmrth-nd-api.honasa-production.net/v1/products/shopAllProducts?pagenumber=' + str(page_num) + '&pagesize=20&categoryId=-1', headers=headers).json()
    for i in json_page['response']['list']['entities']['products'].values():
        Id.append(i['id'])
for z in tqdm(Id):
    jss_page = requests.get(f'https://mmrth-nd-api.honasa-production.net/v1/products/{z}/content', headers=headers).json()
    ig = pd.json_normalize(jss_page)
    for d in range(len(ig)):
        if ig['value'][d] == 'Ingredient List':
            table = ig['value'][d+1]
            print(table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it (I've modified the last for-loop, removed unnecessary code and added some sleep time between requests):

```py
import time

import pandas as pd
import requests

Id = []
for page_num in range(1, 19):
    json_page = requests.get(
        "https://mmrth-nd-api.honasa-production.net/v1/products/shopAllProducts?pagenumber="
        + str(page_num)
        + "&pagesize=20&categoryId=-1"
    ).json()
    for i in json_page["response"]["list"]["entities"]["products"].values():
        Id.append(i["id"])
    time.sleep(1)

for z in Id:
    jss_page = requests.get(
        f"https://mmrth-nd-api.honasa-production.net/v1/products/{z}/content"
    ).json()
    ig = pd.json_normalize(jss_page)

    for d in range(len(ig)):
        if ig["value"][d] == "Ingredient List":
            try:
                table = pd.read_html(ig["value"][d + 1], header=0)
                print(table[0]["Ingredients"].to_list())
            except (KeyError, ValueError, ImportError):
                pass
    time.sleep(1)
```

Output:

```
['CI 77499', 'Mica', 'CI 77510', 'Trimethylsiloxysilicate', 'Hydrogenated Polyisobutene', 'Synthetic Wax', 'Hydrogenated Poly (C6-14 Olefin),', 'Hydrogenated Polydecene', 'Silica Silylate', 'Polybutene', 'Ethylene/Propylene Copolymer', 'Copernicia Cerifera Cera', 'Ascorbyl Palmitate', 'Caprylic/Capric Triglyceride', 'Chamomile Extract', 'Pentaerythrityl Tetra-Di-T-Butyl Hydroxyhydrocinnamate']
['Aqua', 'Butylene Glycol', 'Cyclopentasiloxane', 'Triethylhexanoin', 'Lauryl Peg -8 dimethicone', 'Trimethylsiloxysilicate', 'Ethylhexyl methoxycinnamate', 'Talc', 'Hdi/trimethylol hexyllactone crosspolymer', 'Sodium chloride', 'Disteardimonium hectorite', 'Glycerin', 'Phenoxyethanol', 'Dimethicone', 'Peg/ppg-18/18 dimethicone', 'Titanium dioxide ( nano),', 'Potassium sorbate', 'Sodium dehydroacetate', 'Cyclohexasiloxane', 'Polyglyceryl-3 polydimethylsiloxyethyl dimethicone', 'Methicone', 'Quaternium -90 bentonite', 'Tocopheryl acetate', 'Dimethiconol', 'Ascorbyl palmitate', 'Disodium EDTA', 'Ubiquinone', 'Polysilicone-11', 'Aluminium hydroxide', 'Stearic acid', 'Retinyl palmitate', 'Propylene carbonate', 'Sodium hyaluronate', 'Caprylic/capric triglyceride', 'Silica', 'Hydrogenated dimethicone \xa0Laureth-12', 'Laureth-12', 'Tocopherol', 'CI 77891', 'CI 77491']
['Water', 'Glycerin', 'Niacinamide', 'Propylene Glycol', 'Perlite Volcanic Clay Beads', 'Sodium Ascorbyl Phosphate', 'Alpha Arbutin', 'Carbomer', 'Orange Extract', 'Yogurt Extract', 'Whey Extract', 'Cilantro Extract', 'Bitter melon Extract', 'N-Undecylenoyl Glycine (And) N-Capryloyl Glycin', '2- Phenoxyethanol', 'Triethanolamine', 'IFRA Certified Allergen Free Fragrance', 'Turmeric Powder']
['Water', 'Kaolin Clay', 'Bentonite Clay', 'Glyceryl Monostearate', 'Titanium Dioxide', 'Glycerin', 'Magnesium Aluminium Silicate', 'Caprylic Capric Triglyceride', 'Cetostearyl Alcohol', 'Coconut Oil', 'Sodium Ascorbyl Phosphate', 'Glyceryl Glucoside', 'Lactic Acid', 'Tea Tree Extract', 'Neem Extract', 'Mushroom Extract', 'Licorice Extract', 'Mulberry Extract', 'Aloe Vera Extract', 'Tomato Extract', 'Lemon Extract', 'Triethanolamine', 'Phenoxyethanol', 'Ethylhexylglycerin', 'IFRA Certified Allergen Free Fragrance']
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your support here. It means a lot.

Comment: Actually this solution is giving some output but also throwing an error: (ValueError: No tables found)

Comment: I've expanded the try/except statement to catch this exception too, but beyond that, I fear this is as far as webscrapping can go. Cheers.

Comment: Oh, that I did. Anyways this is more than enough. Thanks, Buddy...